# Is there a way to change preview resolution in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing an app for a specific device. I can change the size of the preview screen with

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 1080, heightDp = 1920)
```

Is there a way to change resolution as well? The screen seems to be ~480p.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass a `device` parameter to @Preview annotation, to change resolution. There is my polygon where I test different devices with different resolutions.

```
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_7", device = Devices.NEXUS_7)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_7_2013", device = Devices.NEXUS_7_2013)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_5", device = Devices.NEXUS_5)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_6", device = Devices.NEXUS_6)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_9", device = Devices.NEXUS_9)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_10", device = Devices.NEXUS_10)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_5X", device = Devices.NEXUS_5X)
@Preview(name = "NEXUS_6P", device = Devices.NEXUS_6P)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_C", device = Devices.PIXEL_C)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL", device = Devices.PIXEL)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_XL", device = Devices.PIXEL_XL)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_2", device = Devices.PIXEL_2)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_2_XL", device = Devices.PIXEL_2_XL)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_3", device = Devices.PIXEL_3)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_3_XL", device = Devices.PIXEL_3_XL)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_3A", device = Devices.PIXEL_3A)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_3A_XL", device = Devices.PIXEL_3A_XL)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_4", device = Devices.PIXEL_4)
@Preview(name = "PIXEL_4_XL", device = Devices.PIXEL_4_XL)
@Preview(name = "AUTOMOTIVE_1024p", device = Devices.AUTOMOTIVE_1024p)
@Composable
fun Polygon() {
  val dm = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics
  val widthPixels = dm.widthPixels
  val heightPixels = dm.heightPixels
  val densityDpi = dm.densityDpi
  val density = dm.density
  val xdpi = dm.xdpi
  val ydpi = dm.ydpi
  val scaledDensity = dm.scaledDensity

  val widthInch = widthPixels.toFloat() / xdpi
  val heightInch = heightPixels.toFloat() / ydpi
  val diagonalInch = sqrt(widthInch * widthInch + heightInch * heightInch).times(100).toInt().toFloat().div(100)

  val isPortrait = LocalConfiguration.current.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
  Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).fillMaxSize(1f),
  ) {
    Text(text = "widthPixels = $widthPixels")
    Text(text = "heightPixels = $heightPixels")
    Text(text = "densityDpi = $densityDpi")
    Text(text = "density = $density")
    Text(text = "xdpi = $xdpi")
    Text(text = "ydpi = $ydpi")
    Text(text = "scaledDensity = $scaledDensity")
    Text(text = "dpWidth = ${widthPixels.toFloat() / density}")
    Text(text = "dpHeight = ${heightPixels.toFloat() / density}")
    Text(text = "diagonalInch = $diagonalInch")
    Text(text = "isPortrait = $isPortrait")
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It turns out that the `Devices` are just a string field for an id of an emulator, so if you're using a custom one all you have to do is pass it's id

Comment: @Miltent - How do I find the id of the emulator?

Comment: @ryanholden8
Device Manager -> Find device in a list -> click "Edit" -> click "Show advanced settings" -> on top of the window below "AVD Name" - "ADV Id"

Comment: `DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity`is deprecated in SDK 34

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [PreviewScreenSizes](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/tooling/preview/PreviewScreenSizes) annotation introduced in [Android Studio Dolphin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-dolphin-release-notes#compose_multipreview_annotations).

Add the [androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview) library to your project, as follows:

```
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
```

Then use the annotation as follows:

```
@PreviewScreenSizes
@Composable
fun MyComposablePreview() {
    MyComposable()
}
```

See the [Preview your UI with composable previews](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews) Android Developers' documentation page for more info.